# The results being retrieved twice SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I've asked something similar before, but as I thought the problem was not the SQL it self I oriented my question to PHP or PDO, that's why I am re-asking this question (To call it in a way). So basically my query is retrieving the data twice (exept the last object), and I have been trying to discover why but can not find the answer. All the once who replied to my other post did not have any idea of why this was happening, that's why I decided to focus this question on the SQL and not in the PHP code, it's self, 've taken this decision because whenever the query is tested on PHPMYADMIN the same duplication problem appears so I guess the problem is on the SQL itself. Thank you in advanced.

Desierd results: Query retriving the data (not twice)

Sample data:

```
    INSERT INTO `personal_posts` (`id`, `body`, `posted_at`, `user_id`, `likes`, `postimg`, `topics`) VALUES
(1, 'post 1', '2017-01-27 00:00:00', 3, 1, NULL, NULL),
(2, 'post 2, '2017-09-10 00:00:00', 1, 1, NULL, NULL),
```

My query:

```
SELECT personal_posts.id, personal_posts.body, personal_posts.posted_at, personal_posts.postimg, personal_posts.likes, users.`username` FROM users, personal_posts, followers
            WHERE (personal_posts.user_id = followers.user_id
            OR personal_posts.user_id = :useridB)
            AND users.id = personal_posts.user_id
            AND follower_id = :userid
            ORDER BY personal_posts.posted_at DESC;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added what you requested @GordonLinoff

Comment: No, you didn't. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  What do you expect if you ask the database to first produce a Cartesian product of all the tables?  Duplicates seem likely.

Perhaps this is the query you want:

```
SELECT pp.id, pp.body, pp.posted_at, pp.postimg, pp.likes, u.username
FROM personal_posts pp JOIN
     users u
     ON pp.user_id = u.id JOIN
     followers f
     ON pp.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE f.follower_id = :userid OR pp.user_id = :useridB
ORDER BY pp.posted_at DESC;
```

This is just a guess, however.  It is at least readable.

Comment: Thanks for the try, in spite of that I am having the same results.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm getting duplicate records, sometimes I add all columns from all tables to see where the duplicates are. So, you can try a query like this (based on Gordon Linoff's answer):

```
SELECT 'pp',
pp.*,
'u',
u.*,
'f',
f.*
FROM personal_posts pp
JOIN users u ON pp.user_id = u.id
JOIN followers f ON pp.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE f.follower_id = :userid OR pp.user_id = :useridB
ORDER BY pp.posted_at DESC;
```

(I've added the 'pp' and other fields in quotes so you can see in your results where one table ends and another table starts.)

You should get results with a lot of columns, but it should show you where the records are different. This would indicate a missing join condition or WHERE clause.

This isn't the final query, but it can help you find the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm new to SQL, there are two differences between the duplicated results, the id and the follower_id (as shown in the following image https://ibb.co/kLtg9Q) So what could be going wrong?